# List all members of a group from the command line in OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, user-accounts

I'’ve tried Googling but not getting anywhere. How can I list all the members of a group called `mygroup` from the command line in OS X?

```
dscl . list /groups
```

Will get me all the groups. But how can I see each group’s members?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use:

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name admin
```

or:

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name staff
```

etc.

Comment: This is my favorite method. Easy peasy, and accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Just add this as an alias in your shell startup file and you can make it a one-word command plus the group name.

Comment: When I tried "dscacheutil -q group" I got 2 paragraphs for group "admin". The two have same name, gid, but different users list. Any idea? Thx!

Comment: Not necessarily complete. `dscacheutil -q group -a name admin` only gave me 1 result, whereas the Accepted Answer's shell script gave me 2 results.

Comment: this is not accurate. it doesn't always lists all members,  see arne's answer below

Comment: dscacheutil -q group -a name admin; Only list one of five admin ids. Where as Jay Browns method below list 5. macos 10.10.5 exact code: group=admin;
for i in $(dscl . list /users);
do [[ $(id -nG $i | grep $group) ]] && echo $i;
done;rc=0

Comment: This method fails for several groups in MacOS 10.15, 11.x and 12.x - e.g. the group 'everyone' that yields empty list. However testing membership for any specific user - the answer is "yes". I wonder why...

Answer (score 75):

There's no standard command that lists all members of a group in OS X, so here's a shell function which does that:

```
members () { dscl . -list /Users | while read user; do printf "$user "; dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "$user" -G "$*"; done | grep "is a member" | cut -d " " -f 1; };
```

Copy the above command-line to the Terminal, and then type `members mygroup` (where *mygroup* is the name of an existing group).

---

Some explanation for those who are interested:

There are **five** different ways (that I know of) that a user can be member of a group in OS X. The command `dscl . -read /Groups/mygroup GroupMembership` isn't guaranteed to output all, or even any, of *mygroup*'s members, because membership also comes from users' *primary group ID*, membership by user's [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), inheritance of membership from one group to another, and memberships that are calculated by the system, such as the group *everyone*.

So rather than trying to keep track of all those, it seems like a better idea to simply check the membership of every user on the system (using [dsmemberutil](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dsmemberutil.1.html)), and that's what the shell function and the script below do.

---

This *members* script is equivalent to the shell function, but has nicer handling of invalid input:

```
#!/bin/bash

# members -- list all members of a group
#
# SYNOPSIS
#   members groupname
#
# http://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-mac-os-x
#  by Arne
# Expected to work on Mac OS 10.5 and newer, tested on 10.6 and 10.7.
# It could be rewritten to work on 10.4 by using "dseditgroup -o checkmember"
# instead of "dsmemberutil checkmembership".
# By using dseditgroup, the script could also be extended to handle
# other Directory Service nodes than the default local node.
#

the_group="$1"
# Input check and usage
  if [[ $# != 1 || $1 == -* || $1 =~ [[:space:]] ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} groupname" >&2
    echo "Lists all members of the group." >&2
    exit 64
  elif (dsmemberutil checkmembership -U root -G "$the_group" 2>&1 \
    | grep "group .* cannot be found") >&2; then
    exit 1
  fi

# Check every user
exec dscl . -list /Users \
  | while read each_username
  do
    printf "$each_username "
    dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "$each_username" -G "$the_group"
  done \
    | grep "is a member" | cut -d " " -f 1

# eof
```

---

Supplementary info:

The five ways of being a group member are:

1. The user's **PrimaryGroupID**
2. Listed in the group's **GroupMembership**
3. [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/uuid.3.html) listed in the group's **GroupMembers**
4. Inherited membership of group X by being a member of group Y which is listed in group X's **NestedGroups**
5. Membership calculated by the system

These can be explored with commands like `dscl . -read /Groups/somegroup`

Example of ***4***: Membership of the Print Operator group __lpoperator_ is inherited by members of the Print Administrator group __lpadmin_, and membership of that group is inherited by the members of the *admin* group.

Example of ***5***:

```
$ dscl . -read /Groups/netaccounts Comment
Comment:
 Group membership calculated by system
 Accounts from a remote directory server
$
```

SEE ALSO
    [id(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/id.1.html), [dscl(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html), [dsmemberutil(1)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dsmemberutil.1.html), [dseditgroup(8)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/dseditgroup.8.html), [DirectoryServiceAttributes(7)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/DirectoryServiceAttributes.7.html), [uuid(3)](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/uuid.3.html)

Comment: This is the kind of peculiarities that I have in mind when I tell people that while OS X is mostly beautiful on the surface it's got some nasty stuff hidden underneath the covers.

Comment: **+1**: This works solidly. Merci.

Comment: This is the info I needed to figure out how to remove myself from the admin group. Turns out removing by username is not enought, you also need to remove the UUID, see https://github.com/drduh/macOS-Security-and-Privacy-Guide/issues/179#issuecomment-266202706

Comment: digit on terminal: groups

Comment: indeed with localaccounts group, using dscacheutils you cannot see using any users while yours displays all of them  (more than 50!). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for illuminating answer. However - are there complementary APIs that allow to do this programmatically (without starting sub-processes or shells) ?? I'm trying all kinds of thing with OpenDirectory framework and API - and can't get it right for some membership types - e.g. 'everyone' whose "Group membership calculated by system". Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

*Note: This was my initial answer, written before I realized **this answer still gives an incomplete result**. (For example, it finds no members of the* everyone *group!) So I wrote [a better answer, which includes a script that lists all members of a group in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-mac-os-x/395738#395738).*

---

*mygroup*'s GroupMembership property can be printed with [dscl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1) like this:

```
dscl . -read /Groups/mygroup GroupMembership
```

But this isn't guaranteed to output all (or even any) of the group's members. What's missing are the users who are member of the group only by having it as their *primary group ID*.

A common example of this in OS X are regular login accounts, which have *staff* (group 20) as their primary group, but are not listed in the GroupMembership property of the *staff* group.

Those users can be found by searching for the numeric *primary group ID* (gid) like this example for the *staff* group (gid 20):

```
dscl . -list /Users PrimaryGroupID | grep " 20$"
```

and the numeric gid (PrimaryGroupID) of *mygroup* is found by:

```
dscl . -read /Groups/mygroup PrimaryGroupID
```

Answer (score 9):

To get all the **groups that a user is in**, you could use the following:

```
id -nG <username>
```

Example Output:

```
staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 everyone localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_ftp com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh
```

Utilising the command above, it is possible to get **all users that belong to a group**:

**OSX**:

```
group=staff;
for i in $(dscl . list /users);
do [[ $(id -nG $i | grep $group) ]] && echo $i;
done
```

**Unix**:

```
group=sudo;
# This only outputs lines that match a username (from the start of line to a colon must not be a hash indicating a comment) 
for i in $(grep -oE "^[^#:]+" /etc/passwd);
do [[ $(id -nG $i | grep $group) ]] && echo $i;
done
```

Comment: This is a nice tip to get list of groups that a user belongs to. But it is the opposite of what the OP was asking, which is list of users that belong to a group.

Comment: @wisbucky this is precisely what I was after. I got here looking for "list all groups of a user". I will suggest an edit to clarify this

Answer (score 4):

> `dscl . -read /Groups/[groupname] | grep GroupMembership`

BE AWARE: The command above does not always display a complete list of ALL group members. E.g. for the group "staff" you only get "root" as a group member which is incomplete. To check it use one of the following commands as a default user (NOT "root"): `id -Gn` OR `groups`

As a result you will see all groups your default logged user is a member of. One of them should be "staff". Thus, besides "root" there are more members of the group "staff", which are not listed by the command `dscl . -read /Groups/[groupname] | grep GroupMembership`. The same goes for the command `dscacheutil -q group -a name staff` which also suggests you that only "root" is a member of the group "staff", which is obviously incomplete.

The only reliable method to get really ALL members of a group in the terminal on OSX is already provided here by Arne Stenström. This is using his shell function resp. his shell script. Both works great!

Answer (score 2):

**Command**

Similar to @duperuser's answer, the following will print out only the users of the group `admin` with spaces in between:

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name admin | grep -e '^users:' | sed 's/users: //'
```

**Output**

Running the above command will produce something like this:

```
root your_username someone_else
```

**Breakdown**

The [`dscacheutil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscacheutil.1.html) command is used to query information about various categories of the system's Directory Service cache. The `-q` option lets you specify the category you want to query. The available categories are group, host, mount, protocol, rpc, service, and user. We further query that category by specifying a key value pair with the `-a` option. In this case, we want to list the group having the key `name` equal to the value `admin`. The `dscacheutil` command above produces output like this:

```
name: admin
password: *
gid: 80
users: root yourusername
```

Next we [pipe](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html) this text into [`grep`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html) and pick out the line containing the string `users:` at the beginning. The `-e` option makes grep recognize [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts). The `^` character specifies that we want `users:` to be at the beginning of the line.

This gives us

```
users: root yourusername
```

Finally, we pass this into sed and replace the text `users:` with the empty string. In [sed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-basics-of-using-the-sed-stream-editor-to-manipulate-text-in-linux), the first letter `s` means to substitute. The text between the first pair of slashes (`/users: /`) is what we want to replace, and the next pair of slashes (`//`) is what we want to substitute (in this case, nothing).

Comment: This is all clear and nice, where it to actually work... but do try your technique with the group 'everyone' and lo and behold --- nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation for this problem which was *derived* from an implementation in a [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835368/how-to-list-all-users-in-a-linux-group/20849247#20849247).  *The routine is somewhat generic, with a directory service lookup hook for any specific platform/architecture, so it can be used without modification on a heterogenous network.*  We've installed a symbolic link to this utility named `zed`.  Other origins for this implementation are mentioned in the attribution section of the script.  This tool is intended to be run on at least OSX, HP-UX, linux, and SunOS, but *hasn't been* tested on SunOS and HP-UX.  The script was tested as far as possible on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 and Mavericks OSX 10.9.1.  The output of this script matches the output for the first shell script implementation for this problem, and is therefore considered correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Lists members of all groups, or optionally just the group
# specified on the command line
#
# Date:         12/30/2013
# Author:       William H. McCloskey, Jr.
# Changes:      Added logic to detect host type & tailor subset of getent (OSX)
# Attribution:
#   The logic for this script was directly lifted from Zed Pobre's work.
#     See below for Copyright notice.
#   The idea to use dscl to emulate a subset of the now defunct getent on OSX
#     came from
#       http://zzamboni.org/\
#         brt/2008/01/21/how-to-emulate-unix-getent-with-macosxs-dscl/
#     with an example implementation lifted from
#       https://github.com/petere/getent-osx/blob/master/getent
#
# Copyright © 2010-2013 by Zed Pobre (zed@debian.org or zed@resonant.org)
#
# Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
# purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
# copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
#

use strict; use warnings;

$ENV{"PATH"} = "/usr/bin:/bin";

# Only run on supported $os:
my $os;
($os)=(`uname -a` =~ /^([\w-]+)/);
unless ($os =~ /(HU-UX|SunOS|Linux|Darwin)/)
    {die "\$getent or equiv. does not exist:  Cannot run on $os\n";}

my $wantedgroup = shift;

my %groupmembers;

my @users;

# Acquire the list of @users based on what is available on this OS:
if ($os =~ /(SunOS|Linux|HP-UX)/) {
    #HP-UX & Solaris assumed to be like Linux; they have not been tested.
    my $usertext = `getent passwd`;
    @users = $usertext =~ /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+):/gm;
};
if ($os =~ /Darwin/) {
    @users = `dscl . -ls /Users`;
    chop @users;
}

# Now just do what Zed did - thanks Zed.
foreach my $userid (@users)
{
    my $usergrouptext = `id -Gn $userid`;
    my @grouplist = split(' ',$usergrouptext);

    foreach my $group (@grouplist)
    {
        $groupmembers{$group}->{$userid} = 1;
    }
}

if($wantedgroup)
{
    print_group_members($wantedgroup);
}
else
{
    foreach my $group (sort keys %groupmembers)
    {
        print "Group ",$group," has the following members:\n";
        print_group_members($group);
        print "\n";
    }
}

sub print_group_members
{
    my ($group) = @_;
    return unless $group;

    foreach my $member (sort keys %{$groupmembers{$group}})
    {
        print $member,"\n";
    }
}
```