# user cannot be found in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, user-groups

After running the script [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/395738/320092) to show all members of the group `wheel`, I got a weird result.

```
The user tempuser cannot be found
There was an unknown error.
```

When I tried `dscacheutil -q user -a name tempuser`, I got nothing. Grepping for `tempuser` in /etc/passwd also gives nothing. So what is this tempuser account doing here and how can I get rid of it?

I have a sneaking suspicion that I created it some time ago while testing, but it seems odd that I could create a user account which most of the OS doesn't seem to know about.

UPDATE: When running `dscl . -read /Users/tempuser`, I get

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
AuthenticationAuthority: ;Kerberosv5;;tempuser@... ;ShadowHash;...
GeneratedUID: ...
Password: *...
PasswordPolicyOptions: ...
RecordName: tempuser
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
```

In contrast, when running that command on my own account, I get those keys, plus the following keys, which *don't* exist for tempuser:

```
PrimaryGroupID: ...
RealName: ...
UniqueID: ...
UserShell: ...
```

So somehow I generated a user without an id and that's why the utilities are complaining?

Comment: Does `dscl . -list /Users` list "tempuser"? If so, what does `dscl . -read /Users/tempuser ` list?

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the suggestion - I added the output to my answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how that tempuser account got created, but however it happened it's missing some critical properties (mostly UniqueID and PrimaryGroupID), so I can't really blame `dscacheutil` for getting confused by it. In any case, it should be safe to delete it with:

```
sudo dscl . -delete /Users/tempuser
```